# How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP in nginx - Webuzo

Tags: nginx, vps

please help me. I'm using vps for my web. I'm using webuzo & install nginx for my website. My web use cloudflare for manage DNS. My web can't access when i open my web with htpps. I'm already try add extra configuration in webuzo with this code but doesn't work.

```
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
```

Any one can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS connections use port 443. So, the following should work for your redirect. But, you'll need another server block with your `listen 80` that actually routes the real traffic to your site.

```
listen 443;
server_name example.com;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
```